# Removing list item from another list

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a list with some elements and I want to remove elements from another list. *An item should be removed if its value `Contain`s (not equals) the value from another list.*

One of the ways is to do this:

```
var MyList = new List<string> { ... }
var ToRemove = new List<string> { ... }
MyList.RemoveAll(_ => ToRemove.Any(_.Contains));
```

It works...

but, I have a *LOT* of lists (>1 million) and since the ToRemove can be sorted, it would make sense to use that in order to speed the process.

It's easy to make a loop that does it, but is there a way to do this with the sorted collections?

---

Update:

On 20k iterations on a text with our forbidden list, I get this:

> Forbidden list as List -> 00:00:07.1993364
>
> Forbidden list as HashSet -> 00:00:07.9749997

It's consistent after multiple runs, so the hashset is slower

Comment: You have over a million lists? Or list items?

Comment: @Rufus: I know how to sort the list, the point I made is that if the list that has the words to exclude is sorted, the process could be a lot faster but I'm trying to see how to do it with the c# collections.

Comment: @Camilo: I have over a million lists, each of them has roughly 7-10 words in them

Comment: OP, is it correct that your current code works like [this](https://rextester.com/OGYV83551) - you want to remove string items from MyList where that string, in part, contains a value from ToRemove?

Comment: @John, yes: we have a list of forbidden words, any string containing one is out.

Comment: An aside from your question: That seems like a very naive attempt. I imagine the last 3 letters of the word "grass" is a forbidden word, so any sentences containing "grass" will be removed.

Comment: HashSet is slower owing to a misunderstanding of how your existing code works. I think Alex's answer was provided on the assumption that the remove line was this: `MyList.RemoveAll(a => ToRemove.Any(b => a == b));`, but since it isn't, as Paul says, a HashSet won't be much help.

Comment: We can have a few false positives, but it's ok, losing part of the data is a problem due to the sheer volume

Comment: The mini benchmark shows that the hashset is a bit slower.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] so we can see the shape of the data involved.

Comment: A few lines of sample data might make it easier for people to debug and test the code locally. It doesn't have to be **real** data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sorting `ToRemove` may be beneficial because of binary search `O(log n)` complexity (you will need to rewrite `_ => ToRemove.Any(_.Contains)`).

But, instead, using a `HashSet<string>` instead of `List<string>` for `ToRemove` will be much faster, because finding an element in a hashset (using `Contains`) is `O(1)` operation.

Also, using `LinkedList<string>` for `MyList` can potentially be beneficial, since removing an item from a linked list is generally faster than removing from an array based list because of array size adjusting.

Comment: I thought about the hashset, but that brings another question: in order to do a match, each string in the MyList has to be hashed; whereas in a plain string compare, the first step is to match the length, so many strings get instantly rejected without being scanned; I'm looking for the optimal solution because we're getting new data all the time.

Comment: @Thomas Surely the cost of hashing the `ToRemove` list is less than the cost of iterating through it every time you want to remove items from one of your numerous lists based on the contents of ToRemove?

Comment: Well, `List<string>` can be potentially faster than `HashSet<string>` only for very small size. But if it is small, you don't really need to care about perf, since it will be fast anyway (the same way, if the the list is small, binary search may be actually more expensive)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a removal of strings that contain strings that are in another list, a HashSet wouldn't be much help.  Actually not much would be unless you were looking for exact full matches or maintain an index of all substrings (expensive and AFIK only SQL Server does this semi-efficiently outside the BigData realm). 
If all you cared about was if it starts with items in 'ToRemove', sorting could help.  Sort the 'MyList' and foreach string in 'ToRemove' custom binary search to find any string starting with that string and RemoveAt index until not starts with, then decrement index backwards removing until not starts with.

Comment: Could you elaborate why `HashSet` wouldn't be much help?

Comment: @Alex He's right, actually. MyList is type `List<string>`, and OP is calling `.Contains()` on the item from MyList for each item of ToRemove (i.e. "does anywhere in the string of MyList contain the word from ToRemove?") - [Example](https://rextester.com/OGYV83551)

Comment: I see, makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for handling those comments for me.  I've been coding 30 years, but am not social, so I've only recently started posting and just got the privilege to comment yesterday.